# XML Feed Structure

Tags: ios, xml, xml-parsing

Is it possible to create a XML feed in the following structure:

```
<item>
<product>
<make>make1</make>
<model>model1</model>
<model>model2</model>
<model>model3</model>
</product>
<product>
<make>make2</make>
<model>model1</model>
<model>model2</model>
</product>
</item>
```

Also how would I parse this so that in first table I have all the makes and in the second table I have all the models related to the make selected

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure, it's possible but why not get rid of `product` and have `<make name=make1>`to get rid of extra nodes and have models children of make. Or better yet use JSON

Comment: I agree, I'd be inclined to restructure this XML a bit. Either be an array of products (in which `make` and `model`) are logical attributes, or be a hierarchical structure (e.g an array of `make` objects, for which there is a `models` object that is an array of `model` objects). A bunch of different structures might make sense. But the XML of the original question doesn't seem quite right to me. And JSON, with it's explicit designation of arrays and dictionaries, definitely makes parsing easier.

Comment: I'd advise against stuffing data content into attributes.  It's very tempting, but not a good idea over the longer haul.  [This thread](http://lists.xml.org/archives/xml-dev/200205/msg01027.html) from a while back discusses a number of canonical issues around the element/attribute distinction and best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with mkrai that you might want to contemplate whether this is the right XML (unless you have no control over it). It's saying that there is an `item`, which is an array of products, for which each product has a `make` attribute, and then an array of `model` attributes. Very strange.

But reading your question that you want a table of makes and for each of those, a table of models, that might suggest an XML like:

```
<makes>
    <make>
        <name>make1</name>
        <models>
            <model>model1</model>
            <model>model3</model>
            <model>model4</model>
        </models>
    </make>
    <make>
        <name>make2</name>
        <models>
            <model>model2</model>
            <model>model5</model>
        </models>
    </make>
</makes>
```

But, before we suggest how you'd use a `NSXMLParser` to parse that, I might first suggest considering JSON. The equivalent JSON might look like:

```
[
    {
        "name": "make1",
        "models": [
            "model1",
            "model3",
            "model4"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "make2",
        "models": [
            "model2",
            "model5"
        ]
    }
]
```

The reason I suggest that, is that unlike `NSXMLParser`, for which you'd need to write a lot of code to parse that simple XML, with JSON, you can do it with one line of code:

```
NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                 options:0
                                                   error:&error];
```

Comment: It's usually a good idea to group a repeating element into a containing element.  Thus <model>s collected into a <models>, <make>s into a <makes>, etc.

Comment: @arayq2 Agreed. That's why I defined my XML that way. But it's good to point out that convention.